# What tag should I use for file size w/ alt text?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

There's a [`<time>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) tag for times, but what should I use for file size?

Right now I'm using,

```
<abbr title="11,201 bytes">10.9 KB</abbr>
```

But I'm wondering if there's something more appropriate.

I *do* want the tooltip to appear on mouse-over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *exact* tag for what you're looking for. I wouldn't use an `<abbr>` since they're reserved for abbreviations and may affect some web-crawlers, etc.
There is a good [list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp) of HTML tags here for reference.

However, for your use case I would adopt a custom-styled `<span>` tag.
It still supports the `title` attribute so the tooltip will appear nonetheless.

If semantics are a concern, consider looking at adding `aria-label` attributes so your HTML is up to the [ARIA spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA).

Comment: I would not recomend the `pre` tag at all as it has a very specific semanitc meaning.

Comment: @JonP true, I think a `span` is probably the way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`data` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-data-element), especially if the human-readable form should be different from the machine-readable one (however, in plain HTML5 it’s not possible to specify the kind of value in a machine-readable way). The `title` attribute has no special meaning here, so you can use it for advisory information.

If you don’t need this, a meaningless `span` with a `title` attribute would do.

The [`abbr` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-abbr-element) should only be used for the actual abbreviation, i.e., "KB". The `title` attribute gives the expansion of the abbreviation.

So for example:

```html
<data value="11201 B" title="11,201 bytes">10.9 <abbr title="kilobyte">KB</abbr></data>
```

```html
<span title="11,201 bytes">10.9 <abbr title="kilobyte">KB</abbr></span>
```